# Display weekly transactions alongside the sum of product price column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have this code in my controller which displays the total amount of product price(weekly)

```php
$weekly = Transaction::where('user_id',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
             return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('W');
             })->map(function ($row) {
                 return $row->sum('product_price');
             });
```

i also have this which displays the transactions(weekly)

```php
$weekly = Transaction::where('user_id',$id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->groupBy(function($date) {
             return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('W');
             });
```

i want to display the weekly transactions alongside the total of the product price(weekly). Please how do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $res = Transaction::select(DB::raw('SUM(product_price) AS total'))
        ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
        ->groupBy(Carbon::parse(created_at)->format('W'))
        ->where('user_id',$id)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Can you just remove the `groupBy` statement and try to get remaining results

Comment: i am getting error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: select SUM(product_price) AS total from `transactions` where `user_id` = 2 order by `created_at` desc)